# ISERR Support in POI

Tags: apache-poi

Does anyone know what do I need to modify to add support to "ISERR" in POI's FormulaEvaluator?

I need to support this evaluation as I'm parsing an Excel file contains "ISERR" using Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Apache POI already supports the [ISERROR function](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/LogicalFunction.html#ISERROR), in 3.11 at least, is that not what you need?

Comment: No, I need ISERR() not ISERROR(). Do you know a way for this?

Comment: How do they differ? Is the logic close enough that it'd be easy to alter one for the other?